# ASP.NET MVC Insert statement into DB Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, debugging

I am making a blog in ASP.NET MVC and when adding a comment to a post, I get this error when trying to `INSERT` into my database:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

[image]

I have also checked the values in my object when the exception happens, but every parameter is filled with the same datatype as defined in the model class.

I have checked my model class and database structure, but cannot find the problem.

```
public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

This is my database Table:

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Specify the columns you are writing to in the `INSERT` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `SQL statement` to include the column names:

```
INSERT INTO Comment 
(PostId, Description, TimeStamp, UserId)
VALUES 
(@PostId, @Description, @TimeStamp, @UserId)
```

In your C# Code:

```
command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Comment (PostId, Description, TimeStamp, UserId)
                        VALUES 
                        (@PostId, @Description, @TimeStamp, @UserId)";
```

Comment: This helped me! I've added the Id in my SQL statement along with the column names and this worked perfectly! Thanks a lot!